# Rescale curve so that it is at constant distance from original one

Tags: matlab, optimization, line

A question I strangely could not find on the internet. Given a complicated curve C (i.e. a curve that you can't fit with polynomials) defined by N points and centered around x0=0.5,0 (blue curve in figure), how can I rescale the curve so that the center is the same and the new curve is located at a constant distance d from the curve C (e.g. green curve in figure)?
[image]

So far the only way I could find is using the MATLAB function bwdist (https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) which computes the Euclidean distance map of a binary image (see code below). However, I'm constrained by the size of my matrix i.e. a curve of 1e5 points is fine but a matrix of size (1e5,1e5) is big for bwdist...so the results using a coarse matrix is an ugly step-wise function. The code is

```
%%% profile
x = linspace(0,1,1e5);
y = -(x-0.5).^2/0.5^2 + 1 - 0.5*(exp(-(x-0.5).^2/2/0.2^2) - exp(-(-0.5).^2/2/0.2^2));

%%% define mask on a region that encompasses the curve
N=512;
mask = ones(N,N);
xm = linspace(0.9*min(x),1.1*max(x),N);
ym = linspace(0.9*min(y),1.1*max(y),N);
[Xm,Ym] = meshgrid(xm,ym);

%%% project curve on mask (i.e. put 0 below curve)
% get point of mask closer to each point of y
DT = delaunayTriangulation(Xm(:),Ym(:));
vi = nearestNeighbor(DT,x',y');
[iv,jv] = ind2sub(size(mask),vi);
% put 1 to indices of mask that are below projected curve
for p=1:length(iv)
    mask(1:iv(p)-1,jv(p)) = 0;
end

%%% get euclidean distance
Ed = bwdist(logical(mask));
Ed = double(Ed);

%%% get contours of Ed at given values (i.e. distances)
cont = contour(Ed,linspace(0,1,50));
% cont has the various curves at given distances from original curve y
```

I add that I first tried moving a point of curve C for a distance d using the normal of the tangent but since the curve is non-linear, this direction is actually not necessarily the one giving the appropriate point. So at some distance, the curve becomes discontinuous because using the tangent does not give the point at a given distance from the curve, only from the considered point on curve C.

[image]

The code is

```
% profil
x = linspace(0,1,1e5);
y = -(x-0.5).^2/0.5^2 + 1 - 0.5*(exp(-(x-0.5).^2/2/0.2^2) - exp(-(-0.5).^2/2/0.2^2));

% create lines at Dist from original line
Dist = linspace(0,2e-1,6);
Dist = Dist(2:end);
Cdist(1).x = x;
Cdist(1).y = y;
Cdist(1).v = 0;
step = 10; % every step points compute normal to point and move points
points = [1:1:length(y)];
for d=1:length(Dist)
    xd = x;
    yd = y;
    for p=1:length(points)
        if points(p)==1
            tang = [-(y(2)-y(1)) (x(2)-x(1))];
            tang = tang/norm(tang);
            xd(1) = xd(1) - Dist(d)*tang(1);
            yd(1) = yd(1) - Dist(d)*tang(2);
        elseif points(p)==length(y)
            tang = [-(y(end)-y(end-1)) (x(end)-x(end-1))];
            tang = tang/norm(tang);
            xd(end) = xd(end) - Dist(d)*tang(1);
            yd(end) = yd(end) - Dist(d)*tang(2);
        else
            tang = [-(y(p+1)-y(p-1)) (x(p+1)-x(p-1))];
            tang = tang/norm(tang);
            xd(p) = xd(p) - Dist(d)*tang(1);
            yd(p) = yd(p) - Dist(d)*tang(2);
        end
    end
    yd(yd<0)=NaN;
    Cdist(d+1).x = xd;
    Cdist(d+1).y = yd;
    Cdist(d+1).v = Dist(d);
end

% plot
cmap=lines(10);
hold on
for c=1:length(Cdist)
    plot(Cdist(c).x,Cdist(c).y,'linewidth',2,'color',cmap(c,:))
end
axis tight
axis equal
axis tight
```

Any idea ?

Comment: hum, I;ve seen this done somewhere. Ultimately you want a circle tangent to your curve. The center of this circle is your new curve. I can't remember now how to do it, but FYI you can always use piecewise splines to fit the curve if you need a equation.

Comment: Thank you I'll have a look. But how would you rescale it once you have an equation ? As aid below I don't mind if the shape changes. It's actually a prerequisit at some point when distance is too large as my second figure shows.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible.

Scaling a curve with respect to a center point while remaining equal distance to the original curve means that all the points on this curve are moving along its normal direction towards the center of scaling, and will eventually, reduce to a point.

Imagine drawing the normal direction of each point on this curve, and extend them to infinity. All these lines should pass through a same point, which is the center of scaling. Unfortunately, this is not the case for your curve.

Comment: Indeed, and my second figure shows what you say. Using the normal direction won't work.Perhaps I should not say "rescale the curve" as I don'tmind if the curve changes shape as I increase the distance, which is what happens when I use bwdist. I just want to find an easier way than using delaunay and bwdistt.